# How do I find item label or plaintext name from URI or QID in SPARQL?

Tags: python, sparql, wikipedia

I have a SPARQL script for finding the birthday and death day of a person, and I want to also get the profession of the person.

This is the query I was using to get the DOB and death date:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?DOB) as ?DOB) (SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP) WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "David Bowie"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item .
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DOB .}            # P569 : Date of birth
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}            # P570 : Date of death
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

And to get the profession I made this modification:

```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?DOB) as ?DOB) (SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP) (SAMPLE(?profession) as ?profession)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "David Bowie"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item.
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DOB .}            # P569 : Date of birth
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .}            # P570 : Date of death
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P106 ?profession .}     # P106 : profession
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel
```

This query will return the birthday and deathday if valid, but for the profession I get `wd:Q33999` in the online query service and in my python script where I'm executing the query I get `'profession': {'type': 'uri', 'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q33999'}`.

This wd:Q33999 links to actor, but I just want the text - 'actor'. Can I select the label associated with wd:33999? Or execute some sort of subquery to find the profession in plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend this part:

```
OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P106 ?profession .}
```

to fetch more related data, like a label:

```
OPTIONAL{
  ?item wdt:P106 ?professionId .
  ?professionId rdfs:label ?profession
}
```

Remember to replace the `rdfs:label` with a label predicate that exists in your data (if different).

In you case I think you'll also need to add some filtering to include only English label:

```
OPTIONAL {
  ...
  FILTER (lang(?profession) = 'en')
}
```

Comment: You can use the SERVICE wikibase:label for any label. For adding the label of ?profession, simply add ?professionLabel to the list of variables.:
```
SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel ?profession ?professionLabel 
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "David Bowie"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item.
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P106 ?profession .}     # P106 : profession
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
```

Comment: Hi Krzystof thanks for your answer! This is great but I see an odd output with the David Bowie example I gave. I added your snippet but now see `ator` as the profession output, which I'm assuming should be `actor`. 'Eminem' as a search returns `rapper` as expected, and 'Taylor Swift' returns `singer`, but other actors also return `ator`. Is this do do with the rdfs predicate you mentioned? Sorry I'm a beginner with SPARQL!

Comment: @user14462428 you forgot to add the language filter for English then. "ator" is for Lingua Franca Nova, see

Comment: Also, given that you use `sample`, you'll miss many occupations and with sample you might get a different profession each time

Comment: `SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?DOB) as ?DOB) (SAMPLE(?RIP) as ?RIP) (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?pl; separator=", ") as ?professions)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item ?label "David Bowie"@en.  
  ?article schema:about ?item.
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en" .
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P569 ?DOB .}  
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P570 ?RIP .} 
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P106/rdfs:label ?pl FILTER (lang(?pl) = 'en')} 
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }    
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel`